# does "full form" refers to "a whole body" in this context? does "chiefly" refers only to "raps" or not?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

does "full form" refers to "a whole body" in this context?

> Her mediumship consisted **chiefly** of raps (often of great power),
>   spirit lights, direct writing, and the appearance of materialized
>   hands. **Full form** materializations, which had been an occasional
>   feature of her sittings in America, were rare with her in England. On
>   a number of occasions objects in the séance-room were moved by spirit
>   agency, and in some cases brought from another room.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Full form" here does refer to a whole body. It refers to the entirety of the thing being referenced. In this case the thing that has been referenced is the hands so full form would refer to the entire thing(we can assume here that it would be a human or similar) including the hands

The "chiefly" refers to the entire list that follows it. So it mostly consists of the four things mentioned, but other things may be used occasionally